# Reading array of regs using Verilator and VPI

Tags: verilog, verilator, vpi

So I have the following register defined in my verilog

```
reg [31:0] register_mem [0:15]/* verilator public */;
```

My goal is from my verilator c++ code to read each of the 16 values stored in it.

I have found that the documentation for this VPI stuff is rather difficult to find. I still cannot figure out what a `t_vpi_vecval` is and what its parameters are or if it is even the right approach.

Here is my approach at reading the 5th value in the register

```
unsigned int read_regs() {
    const std::string path = "TOP.TOP.cpu.reg_file.register_mem";
    vpiHandle vh1 = vpi_handle_by_name((PLI_BYTE8*)path.c_str(), NULL);
    if (!vh1) { 
        printf("Name %s", path.c_str());
        vl_fatal(__FILE__, __LINE__, "sim_main", "No handle found: ");
    }
    const char* name = vpi_get_str(vpiName, vh1);


    s_vpi_value v;
    v.format = vpiVectorVal;
    vpi_get_value(vh1, &v);
    return v.value.vector[4].aval;
}
```

No-matter what I do here the method returns 0 suggesting that I am not looking at the register_mem array.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

In order to get values of the array, you need to get values for every element of an array separately. VPI does not return values for the full array.

Actually the handle which you get for an array is a handle of the `vpiRegArray` type. It can be iterated to access every separate element.

Here is a simple code which does the iteration and prints values of every element in the array:

```
#include "vpi_user.h"

PLI_INT32 preg_calltf( char *txt ) {
    vpiHandle hreg = vpi_handle_by_name("rarr.register_mem", 0);
    vpi_printf("reg type: %s\n", vpi_get_str(vpiType, hreg)); // vpiRegArray

    s_vpi_value val = {vpiDecStrVal}; // struct t_vpi_value

    vpiHandle arrayIterator = vpi_iterate( vpiReg, hreg); 
    if( arrayIterator != NULL ) {
        vpiHandle item = NULL;
        while( NULL != ( item = vpi_scan( arrayIterator ) ) ) {
            vpi_get_value(item, &val);
            vpi_printf("item type: %s = %s\n", vpi_get_str(vpiType, item), val.value.str); // vpiReg
            vpi_free_object( item );
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In this case I initialized the `val` with `vpiDecStrVal`. It instructs the compiler to prepare value results as a decimal string. The value is now accessible as `val.value.str`. You have multiple choices to get string or binary data in 2-state or 4-state representation.

For 2-state values up to 32 bit you can use an integer formatting. However, for longer values or 4-state, you need `vpiVectorVal`. It actually requests verilog to create 2 arrays of 32-bit integers, aval and bval. Both have sizes big enough to keep all bits of the value. Combination of bits in aval and bval represent the 4-state value of all bits in the vector.

All vpi information is available in LRM including relation diagrams and data structures. There are also some books, for example "the verilog pli handbook" by Sutherland.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me. A few things deviate. The type printing line reports that it is a ```vpiMemory``` (If this means it synthesized into brams instead of flip flops then that is great as I wrote it to be synchronously accessed so it would be a Bram). However the iterator is always null for me so it never enters the loop. Is it possible that it matters that this value is in a submodule of the main module?

Comment: Try to use `vpiMemoryWord` for iteratator, instead of `vipReg`

Comment: Bingo! That is it! Thankyou so much!